# Annotation/Tooltip throws error on invalid Slot /Hide Slot from function

Tags: evaluation, hold, tooltip

While trying to create a pretty version of `Trace`, I stumbled across a weird issue which I finally tracked down to the following:

```
Annotation[0, Hold@Slot@i]
```

This expression throws an error:

> Function::slot: Slot[i] (in #1&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.

After even more digging, I found the definition that causes the issue:

```
WrappersDump`WrapperToBoxes[Annotation[expr_], data_, fmt_] := 
  TagBox[MakeBoxes[expr, fmt], Annotation[#, data] &];
```

Obviously, the `Function` around `Annotation` sees the invalid `Slot` and starts to complain.

**The question is now:** How can I avoid this?

To give a bit more context: The issue is arising inside my `Trace` postprocessor, that, among other things, creates `Tooltip`s for all expression in the trace (similar to `Tooltip[Short[#],#]&`). Since `Trace` wraps everything in `HoldForm`, nearly everything works perfectly, until there is an invalid `Slot` somewhere (which originates from a piece of code that builds dynamically builds a `Function`), thanks to `Tooltip` using `Annotation`.

### Update 2 - A more reasonable example

Since the above example admittedly seems extremely contrived, I'll try to provide a better one:

Consider the following function to shorten the output of `Trace`:

```
shortenTrace[l_List] := shortenTrace /@ l
shortenTrace[i_] := Tooltip[Short[i, 0.1], i]
```

This simply `Short`ens every item in the trace and places the long expression in the tooltip. This works great:

```
Table[Print@i,{i,3}]//Trace//shortenTrace
(* 1 *)
(* 2 *)
(* 3 *)
(* {<<1>>,{{i,1},Print<<1>><<1>>],{<<9>>[<<1>>],1},Null},{{i,2},Print<<1>><<1>>],{<<9>>[<<1>>],2},Null},{{i,3},Print<<1>><<1>>],{<<9>>[<<1>>],3},Null},{<<1>>}} *)
```

Now consider this example:

```
Table[With[{s = Slot@i}, s &], {i, 3}]
(* {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &} *)
```

Let's trace it:

```
Table[With[{s=Slot@i},s&],{i,3}]//Trace
(* {Table[With[{s=Slot[i]},s&],{i,3}],{With[{s=Slot[i]},s&],{{i,1},#1},#1&},{With[{s=Slot[i]},s&],{{i,2},#2},#2&},{With[{s=Slot[i]},s&],{{i,3},#3},#3&},{#1&,#2&,#3&}} *)

Table[With[{s=Slot@i},s&],{i,3}]//Trace//shortenTrace
Function::slot: Slot[i] (in #1&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.
Function::slot: Slot[i] (in #1&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.
Function::slot: Slot[i] (in #1&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.
General::stop: Further output of Function::slot will be suppressed during this calculation.
(* {<<1>>,{<<1>>,{{i,1},#1},#1&},{<<1>>,{{i,2},#2},#2&},{<<1>>,{{i,3},#3},#3&},{#1&,#2&,#3&}} *)
```

As you can see, the trace output contains `Slot[i]`, which causes the problem in `shortenTrace`⟶`Tooltip`⟶`Annotation`.

### Update

I thought about it some more and found a solution (see answer below).

Also: **Should this be considered a bug?** It seems to me that a function like `Tooltip` that's purely for display purposes should break when trying to display semantically incorrect expressions.

Comment: So `Annotation[0, Hold@Slot@i]` causes the problem, but what is a minimal example that makes sense and produces the problem. This piece is invalid so it throws an error, can you show a valid piece of code which behaves incorrectly? (sorry if I missed something)

Comment: @Kuba I added an example that is closer to my real-world issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I found an answer:

```
Annotation[0,Slot@i/.s:(Slot|SlotSequence):>Annotation[s,"Inactive"]]
```

or

```
Tooltip[0,Slot@i/.s:(Slot|SlotSequence):>Annotation[s,"Inactive"]]
```

This simply uses `Annotation` (kind of ironic) to hide `Slot` from `Function`. Due to the nature of `Annotation`, this is invisible when displayed. It is also straightforward to uniquely identify the "protected" `Slot`s and unprotect them. One could even use a `Unique` symbol in place of `"Inactive"` to go a step further.

Comment: Consider possibly `s : (Slot | SlotSequence) :> Defer[s]` as a shorter alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to judge it, will think about that, meanwhile since Tooltip is meant for display anyway we can speed up formatting so that `#i` won't interfere with `Annotiation's` definitions:

```
shortenTrace // ClearAll
shortenTrace[l_List] := shortenTrace /@ l
shortenTrace[i_HoldForm] := Tooltip[
  Short[i, 0.1]
, ToString[#, InputForm]&[Unevaluated @@ i]
]
```

At the beginning I had `MakeBoxes[i]` but, as noticed by OP, it won't help with e.g. `Dynamic[#]` as it typesetts to `DynamicBox[ToBoxes[#1, StandardForm]]` so `#` can still interfere

Comment: This seems a lot more straightforward than my approach, thanks - however, it seems to have issues when the tooltip contains `Dynamic` expressions... (e.g. simply `Dynamic@i` instead of `i`). I'll think about whether this is an issue of this solution or simply a design flaw on my part

Comment: Thanks for the update - unfortunately, in my case, `ToString` won't work either (although it works a lot better) for all inputs, as some of the tooltips are built containing `Dynamic`, so that `ToString` breaks them. It seems that any method that tries to transform the tooltip content is doomed if there is a `Dynamic` in there that needs to stay

Comment: One example: Let's try to fix `Tooltip[Short[i, 0.1], Short[i, 0.3]]`, i.e we also limit the length of the tooltip. If I wrap the `ToString` around, tooltip reads `Short[...]`, as `Short` is only interpreted for display. If I put it inside, the tooltip is shortened differently, as it's just a string now (e.g. `{0,… , 0}` instead of `{0,<<8>>,0}` for `Short [Table[0, 10], 0.1]`)

Comment: How so? (What I wanted to show with the example is that, depending on what the tooltip should show, wrapping it in `ToString` to hide `Slot@i` breaks other things, e.g. a `Short` wrapper)

Comment: @Mathe172 if you don't want strings then I'd go with your solution.

Comment: After thinking about it some more, that seems like that's the best solution in my case, yes. Anyway, thanks a lot for the suggestions, still learned few nice tricks from this!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to patch the internal function itself, e.g.

```
WrappersDump`WrapperToBoxes[Annotation[expr_, data_], fmt_] := 
  TagBox[
    MakeBoxes[expr, fmt], 
    Function[BoxForm`x, Annotation[BoxForm`x, data]]
  ]
```

- I cannot promise this will not introduce bugs of its own so in practice I would use Kuba's method, specifically the `ToString` variant.
- Don't miss the three-parameter `Annotation` rule if you pursue this, for e.g. `Annotation[0, Hold@Slot@x, "Tooltip"]`